# What does "would be caught dead" mean?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I faced this sentence actually:

> One **would be caught dead** without one of these.

What does "would be caught dead" mean?

Comment: This is odd construction. Usually I would expect "One would**n't** be caught dead without one of these" to indicate that even if you were dead you wouldn't want to be without one. I wonder if this is like the BrE/AmE *Couldn't care less / could care less*. What is your Locale? Are you positive it was **would** ?

Comment: The meaning you said for roughly is ok. Actually it was in a film once a person was interesting sb else for buying a product. Yes i think so it was would

Answer (score 5):

The fixed phrase is **wouldn't be caught dead [in circumstance]**.

It means "would not allow oneself to be seen in this circumstance, even if you had the excuse of being dead".  For example, "She wouldn't be caught dead without her high heels and shades".  It means she always wore high heels and shades when in public.

Because the phrase is used a lot, it **sometimes loses the negation**, and "would be caught dead" means the identical thing to "wouldn't be caught dead".  (In the same way as "could care less" means the same as "couldn't care less".)

Also, as a form of **exaggerated understatement** ([litotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes#Examples)), you will occasionally see "I would be caught dead in" to mean "Absolute opposite of wouldn't be caught dead in".  For example, someone at Pinterest lists her favourites as "[Dresses I would be caught dead in :)](https://www.pinterest.com/blondiebelle/dresses-i-would-be-caught-dead-in/)"

Your example might be either of these second forms: without context it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Do you know if the *could/couldn't* is a AmE/BrE thing? It's always been a bug-bear of mine, as they don't mean the same thing.

Comment: @Smock I believe AmE is always "wouldn't", "couldn't" etc.  I think I've only really heard a fraction of BrE speakers drop the negation without intending any difference in meaning, and they also say "search with a tooth-comb" instead of "search with a fine-toothed comb".  I suspect it's regional UK usage, but can't be sure.

Comment: As a BrE native speaker I've never heard of searching with a tooth-comb - it just doesn't make sense. Also this seems to point to it being AmE that use *could care less* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_American_and_British_English#Figures_of_speech You're answer is spot on though so +1

Comment: @jonathanjo i suppose you're right they drop that negation cause i have checked the transcript it was would . But the meaning i think is what smock has mentioned above

Comment: @Smock The two people I've known who said "tooth-comb" were from East Anglia, specifically Ipswich and Norwich, and it was memorable to my London ears -- they said it didn't make any sense to them either, it was just an expression.

Comment: @jonathanjo Fair enough! There's probably BrE speakers that use *could care less* too by osmosis (and watching American TV shows). It still *grinds my gears* though :)

Comment: @Smock I think corruption through approximate repetition is the mechanism for this kind of thing, I know someone who said "San Fairy Ann" (I've never seen it written) which she learned from her family, none of whom knew it was French (_Ça ne fait rien_)

Comment: Brits often say "seen dead", e.g. my father wouldn't be seen dead wearing brown shoes.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey we're wondering if "would seen dead" vs "wouldn't be seen dead" is regional in any way.

Comment: I have never heard anybody say "would seen dead", I promise you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of "would be caught dead" here https://youtu.be/PcE5ne9SqH8?t=80
In my opinion it is like the Dave Goreman example of "a bowl in a china shop", where people hear it, don't quite understand it, repeat it incorrectly and it catches on.